# Json or native pojo

Tags: java, json, web-services, jackson, jsonresponse

I have debate with my team, 
I have a rest ws  that return something in certian format
The format look something like that

```
{  
    Name:{  
        Inner:[  
            {  
                inner:[  
                    {  
                        inner:"hdjdjd"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In the ws I return data in this format only once.

My teams think that I should create the json using jacksons object node in the response method.
And I think that I should model the format in pojo class and then return the the class json represantation (using jackson)
What is the right option?

Comment: Whatever gets the job done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a matter of taste.

If this JSON format uses not once, I advise you to create [DTO or POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425302/what-is-the-difference-between-pojo-plain-old-java-object-and-dto-data-transf)* object and return it.

Otherwise, return a jacksons object node, why not?

> *
>   All DTOs are POJOs, but not all POJOs are DTOs. An example of POJO
>   that is not a DTO is a business class that contains state and behavior
>   (business logic).

Comment: Becasue the code is much less readable, instead of  creating object of the return format I creates json object which is not native to java and I think- new Format(.....) instead of new ObjectNode().put.put..... etc.. is more readble, isnt it?

Comment: @user5723395, yes, it will be more readable and compactly in the response method, but you need to create a new class that doesn't contain any logic and keeps only data

Comment: This is the idea of DTO design pattern

Comment: I see the following advantages in using a POJO 1) Type checking, 2) Clarity in the response structure, 3) Selective Deserialization ability. 4) Code reusability when the pojos are externalized by the serving service. Why not a POJO then?

Comment: @Prasanna I agree. It was a while ago, I need to revise this answer.

Comment: @Prasanna The Jacksons representation is the only option when the structure of JSON is unknown or its format is changing dynamically and unpredictably. In such cases, it's better to have a `JSONNode` instead of a `POJO` with abstract `Object` or `Map<String, String>` fields

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I totally agree.